# what is this javascript expression for

Tags: javascript, operators

I have worked with javascript during 2 years now, but I have never seen an expression like this one. in google chrome console I have typed this

```
var a=456;
var b=789;
```

then I typed this

```
a|=b
```

and the result was `989`

can someone tell me what is this expression for, and why is the result `989`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the expression

```
a|=b;
```

is like when you do `a+=b;` it's equivalent to

```
a = a | b;
```

the operator `|` is the `OR`, not like the operator `||`. this one is used as the operator `OR` for binary operations

```
5   |  1   ->     0101 | 0001          ->      0101    ->    5
```

in your case

```
456 | 789  ->  111001000 | 1100010101  ->   1111011101  ->    989
```

Answer (score 4):

That is a bitwise OR operation. When used in that fashion it is "or equals" where the result is assigned to the variable.

```
 111001000 //456
1100010101 //789
1111011101 //989
```

Answer (score 3):

That expression is called bitwise `or`, with assignment. It takes the each individual bit position of each number, and returns a `1` for that bit if it is `1` at that position in either of the numbers, otherwise assigning `0` if both are `0`.

See the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for other such bitwise operations.

It is more commonly used in systems languages like C and C++.